# React - On click, modal loads faster than the API response defined in an action, resulting in an empty modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Good evening everybody!

I'm a total beginner in React and Redux so please bear with me if this sounds stupid.

I'm trying to perform an API call using axios whose response data I need to print onto a modal.

So, if I define the axios.get within a function in the same component it gets the response and I store it to a state and then I display the state in the modal and everything works fine.

But if I do the same using actions and reducers I get an empty the modal the first time I click it.

**Without Actions and Reducers**

```
handleImageClick() {
    axios.get(`http://demoapiwebsite`)
        .then(response => {
            response = JSON.stringify(response.data,null,"\t");
            this.setState({ imageDetails: response })  //Modal applies the data from the state imageDetails.
            this.setState({ selectedReceiptDetails: true }); // Toggles the modal.
        });
}
```

**With Actions and Reducers**

**ACTION CREATOR**

```
export function getImageDetails() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get(`http://demoapiwebsite`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: IMAGE_DETAILS,
                    payload: response.data
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            })
    }
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
import {
    IMAGE_DETAILS,
} from '../actions/types';

export default function (state = {imageDetails:''}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case (IMAGE_DETAILS):
            return { ...state, imageDetails: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**COMPONENT**

```
 handleImageClick() {
        this.setState({ imageDetails : JSON.stringify(this.props.imageDetails,null,"\t")});
        console.log(this.state.imageDetails)
        this.setState({ selectedReceiptDetails: true }); //Toggles the modal. 
    }



//Modal that sets this.state.selectedReceiptDetails to the body



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        receiptDetails: state.services.receiptDetails,
        imageDetails: state.services.imageDetails
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getImageDetails })(ReceiptService);
```

Please Help!

Comment: where do you call getImageDetails() method ?

Comment: can i see `render()`

Comment: where is your `App.js` component?

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling async operation then you must have some Loading block of code before data is available to redux store. Important point about component is it always render with initial state/once after calling fetch action and before async data arrive.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 //change the loading state to false if next props is data.
}
```